# Docker-compose continuous integration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to the docker technology. I actually have a mission to create using docker-compose an environment for continuous integration, here's the docker-compose I made but when running docker-compose up I still get some errors such as sonar exception: Database connexion failed.
Actual OS is oracle linux under VirtualBox windows.

```
version: '2'

networks:
  devnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
 nexus:
  image: sonatype/nexus
  container_name: nexus
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
  networks:
    - devnet
  volumes:
    - "/opt/nexus/:/var/lib/nexus"

 jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  container_name: jenkins
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  networks:
    - devnet
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home"


 mongodb:
  image: mongo
  networks:
  - devnet
  ports:
    - 8085:8085  
  environment:
    - MONGODB_USER=root
    - MONGODB_DATABASE=srsmongodb
    - MONGODB_PASS=root
  volumes:
    - /srv/docker/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb
  restart: always

 tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    container_name: tomcat
    networks:
    - devnet
    volumes:
      - ./target/ROOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    restart: always

 sonarqube:
  image: sonarqube
  container_name: sonarqube
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - devnet
  environment:
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=root
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=root
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://sonardb:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
  volumes:
    - "/opt/sonar/:/var/lib/sonar"
  depends_on:
    - mysql

 mysql:
  image: mysql
  networks:
    - devnet
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 3307:3307
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - /opt/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=sonardb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you are confusing the DNS name of the MySQL database with the name of the MySQL database. In your example, the JDBC URL for the `sonarqube` image should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/sonardb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

When you create a network in Docker Compose, the services inside that network will be available by DNS name that is the same as the service. In this case, `mysql` will resolve to the IP address of the MySQL container. The environment variables you have provided to the `mysql` service will create a database named `sonardb`.

See specifically the Links section of https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links:

> by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name. In the following example, db is reachable from web at the hostnames db and database